# CakePHP Routing, using a language prefix with a default prefix

Tags: cakephp, routes, default, prefix

I'm trying to create a routing prefix that would be default.

http://localhost/heb/mycont would leave to the Hebrew page, while

http://localhost/mycont would lead to the English page.

```
Router::connect('/:language/mycont',array('controller'=>'contname','action'=>'index'),array('language'=>'[a-z]{0,3}'));
```

This code allows me to use 0-3 letters for language, but it still requires a language!

http://localhost/a/mycont would work

http://localhost/mycont doesn't work

Any ideas how to fix that?
Is it even possible with the default routing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution was simply to setup the / to a specific language, while everything else is marked
/:language/

That way I did not make duplicated routes.

Answer (score 3):

Let me preface this by stating that I'm not a routing expert, but in this case, it makes sense that what you have wouldn't work because the route is expecting a language parameter; the route won't match if it's not there.

To "fix" (quoted since it's not really broken), you might want to try setting your default locale and, in your `AppController`, overwrite if a `:language` value is present.

Comment: This looks like a quick and solid solution to me!  The only other reasonable option that I can think of would be to override the Router::connect function so that it will set the default :language value if none is present.  But that might be overkill.